# Why is the external hard drive not opened by Windows 10?

Tags: external-hard-drive, disk-management

I have a wd external hard drive that is recognized by windows in device manager but not showing in windows explorer.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried a different USB port?  Are you using the original power cable for the device?

Comment: Is there supposed to be data already on this drive?

Comment: Yes ............

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the disk in Device Manager.

- If the only entry in the context menu is Initialize,
  then select it. Otherwise, skip this step.
- Next, format the drive as NTFS from the same context menu of
  Device Manager.
- Last, assign the disk a drive-letter.

If any of the above operations fails, the disk is defective.

(This assumes that there is no data on the disk that needs
saving.)